# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, group-theory

I have this set:
$$I_a = \{ax+(7-a^2)y : x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
with $a$ integer. I have two tasks over it:

1) Prove that $I_a$ is subgroup of  $\mathbb{Z}$;

2) Fully characterize this subgroup.

I did the first task, but for the second I was thinking on cases, that is, if $a$ is equal to $7k,  7k\pm 1,7k\pm 2$ or  $7k \pm 3$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I was successful with $a= 7k$ (this is: $\langle 7 \rangle = I_a$), but I can't with the other cases. Some hints?

Comment: Do you know that $I_a=\langle a\rangle+\langle 7-a^2\rangle=\langle \gcd(a,7-a^2)\rangle$? (where $\gcd$ is the greatest common divisor)

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need explicitly gcd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\:(1)\:\ I = a\,\mathbb Z\! +\! b\, \mathbb Z\:$ is closed under subtraction so a subgroup of $\left<\mathbb Z, +\right>$ by the [subgroup test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test)

$\rm(2)\:\ \{0\}\ne I\:$ has a least positive $\rm\:c.\:$ Being a group, $\rm\:I \supseteq c\:\mathbb Z.\:$ This is an equality (else there exists $\rm\:d\in I\:$ with $\rm\:nc < d < (n\!+\!1)c,\:$ so $\rm\ 0 < d\!-\!nc < c\:$ and $\rm\:d\!-\!nc \in I,\:$ contra leastness of $\rm\:c).\:$ Thus $\rm\:a,b\in I = c\,\mathbb Z\:\Rightarrow\:\color{#0a0}{c\:|\:a,b}.\:$ $\rm\:d\:|\:a,b\:\Rightarrow\:d\:|\:c = j\,a\!+\!k\,b\:\Rightarrow\: \color{#c00}{d\le c}.\:$ Thus $\rm\,\ c = gcd(a,b),\: $ being a $\color{#c00}{\rm greatest}\ \rm \color{#0a0}{common\ divisor}$ of $\rm\:a,b$.

But $\rm\:gcd(a,b\!-\!an) = gcd(a,b)\:$ since if $\rm\:c\:|\:a\:$ then $\rm\:c\:|\:b\!-\!an\iff c\:|\:b.\:$

So $\rm\:\ \ gcd(a,7-a^2) = gcd(a,7) = c,\:$ where $\rm\: c = 7\:$ if $\rm\:7\:|\:a,\:$ else $\rm\:c = 1$.

Answer (score 6):

First, can you show that 7 is in $I_a$?

Then, can you show that if there is even one number in $I_a$ that isn't a multiple of 7, then $I_a$ is all of $\bf Z$?

Answer (score 5):

To ellaborate on my comment:
**Hint:** $I_a=\langle a\rangle+\langle 7-a^2\rangle=\langle \gcd(a,7-a^2)\rangle$ 
(where $\gcd$ is the greatest common divisor)
Denote $d=\gcd(a,7-a^2)$. $d$ divides $a$, and $d$ divides $7-a^2$ (clearly $d$ divides $a^2$). Can you proceed?

Comment: I think it's a brilliant hint.

Comment: Whoever downvoted - care to explain? You think it is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Prove this general fact first: Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $S = \{ ax + by : x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$ Then $S = n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n=\gcd(a,b).$ An outline of a proof is: Prove that the least positive element of $S$ is a $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b.$ Call this number $n.$ Show all integer multiples of $n$ are in $S$, so $ n\mathbb{Z} \subseteq S.$ Now pick some element $s\in S.$ By the division algorithm, we can write $s=qn + r$ where $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq r< n.$ Since $s,qn \in S$ and $r=s-qn$, we have $r\in S.$ We picked $n$ to be the least positive element of $S$, so $r=0$ and $s=qn$, so $S\subseteq n\mathbb{Z}.$