# A question about a cyclic sub-group

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that $(H,+)$ is a cyclic sub-group of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ when $H=\{30x+42y+72z:x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

---

Attempt:
First, $H\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ since the addition of integer numbers, yields an integer number.
Now, we show the closure of $H$ with ($+$). Therefore, let $a_1=30x_1+42y_1+72z_1$, $a_2=30x_2+42y_2+72z_2$. We shall show that $a_1+a_2\in H$. Thus: $$a_1+a_2=30x_1+42y_1+72z_1+30x_2+42y_2+72z_2=30(x_1+x_2)+42(y_1+y_2)+72(z_1+z_2)\in H$$

In addition, we should show the existence of the opposite number, for each number in $H$. Hence, let $H \ni h=30x_1+42y_1+72z_1$. We define $H \ni h^{-1}=30(-x_1)+42(-y_1)+72(-z_1)$, therefore, we have that: $$h+h^{-1}=30(x_1-x_1)+42(y_1-y_1)+72(z_1-z_1)=0+0+0=0$$

Therefore, $(H,+)$ is a sub-group of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.
The last is to show that $(H,+)$ is a cyclic group, so for that, we shall look at the Gcd of $(30,42,72)$, when $(30,42,72)=6$, so by the definition of being in $H$. $$H=\{30x+42y+72z:x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
So $30x+42y+72z=6(5x+7x+12z)=6k$, when $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ then 6 is a creator element of $H$, thus, $(H,+)$ is cyclic. In conclusion, we have that $(H,+)$ is a cyclotomic sub-group of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

- I don't know If I got it right, and my way is correct, so I will be glad if you can tell me whether my attempt for that question is correct, or not.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a cyclotomic subgroup? Do you mean *cyclic* subgroup? In this case you can use a theorem ( I know you like this): every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes I am sorry.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I fixed it.

Comment: Good. So all you need to do is to verify that $H$ is a subgroup.  Show that $x-y\in H$ for all $x,y\in H$ and you are done - subgroup axiom! You can combine $x+y\in H$ and $-y\in H$ this way. Obviously $0\in H$, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have showed that, no? can you look carefully?

Comment: No, it's your job to look carefully. You have shown $x+y\in H$, but that is unnecessary then if you show first $x-y\in H$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes i'm sorry! what about the proof that the subgroup is cyclic, is it correct?

Comment: It is unnecessary, too. *Every* subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. This is a Theorem, and you like Theorems. Did you find this in the meantime? And since $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is cyclic, we are done.

Comment: @DietrichBurde didn't get it. Why is it unnecessary? In order to show that she is a subgroup, I need to see that she is closed to the + method, and that she has an opposite number for each number in the group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok got it. thanks!

Comment: It seems you are not yet familiar with said general result about subgroups of cyclic groups but instead seek a direct proof, so I closed it as a dupe of the familiar Bezout style proof. The cyclic group form is also a dupe.

Comment: If you know a little group theory note that that "closed under subtraction" is simply the [subgroup test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/150785/242) $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque since the gcd of three numbers is 6, then I can say that H is actually defined to be all integer number to hold $6x$ when $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ so-6 is an the element creator of $H$ so that $H$ with + is cyclic?

Comment: @BillDubuque btw, and I'm sorry for bothering you, can you tell me why subtraction, and not +? because I have a plus method in the subgroup.